# Stellar Blockexplorer API call for looking up exact amount transferred

Tags: horizon

I am looking for a Stellar Blockexplorer API which lets me look up (given an address and transaction hash) the exact amount in Lumen that was transferred in a transaction as a single string.
[Example with bitcoin:](https://blockchain.info/q/txresult/b1ddc46ad47f6f95d75129281b22636d5b19a06bcf534305b018fd8e688265e1/3GZSJ47MPBw3swTZtCTSK8XeZNPed25bf9)

## Background:

Given a transaction Hash I need to look up 3 things things

- The name/code of the token
- The amount transferred
- The address the transaction was sent to.

An API call like [this:](https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/93858036283650049) lets me look up these 3 things but unfortunately, I have to parse the JSON data. Now to give you background on why I cannot do this:
I am developing a smart contract on Ethereum that lets users swap Ether for other currencies. I am using [Oraclize:](http://www.oraclize.it/) to make an external API call that verifies whether a transaction occurred. Now the very problem is that I cannot parse the JSON input in my contract. Any string operation is extremely expensive and would defy the purpose.

Any hint is appreciated thank you!

**Edit [28.01.19]**
I found the solution. The json must be parsed before I make the query using oracalizes services like [such:](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#VVJMKEdFVCk=:anNvbihodHRwczovL2hvcml6b24uc3RlbGxhci5vcmcvb3BlcmF0aW9ucy85Mzg1ODAzNjI4MzY1MDA0OSkuW3RvLGFtb3VudCxwYWdpbmdfdG9rZW5d)

Answer (score 1):

Stellar **Core** is the bitcoin mining nodes, and **Horizon** is the API extended from Core for users. So you are looking for Horizon:

Public net Horizon: https://horizon.stellar.org/

---

**[EDITED, 2018-01-29]** Two steps:

**Step 1 - tx_hash to envelop_xdr, using API**

Use the **`/transaction/:hash`** API with the **hash**, **to get the "envelope_xdr"** (which contains tx details).

e.g. For hash="f282160d542c42c1f8b15cf0c3872a7b29c088e0890113e78e06c8e4b6492ebc", see 
https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/f282160d542c42c1f8b15cf0c3872a7b29c088e0890113e78e06c8e4b6492ebc

=> "envelope_xdr"="AAAAAApiCoxuNTkvHbKZLUZrGmMupURih7+YdkzROUWYTThsAAAAZAAdiaUAAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAqUwxrV7Z/dWAk60+vKYjk2ncSsilO9R27dz7fQOE+RIAAAABYWEAAAAAAAAKYgqMbjU5Lx2ymS1GaxpjLqVEYoe/mHZM0TlFmE04bAAAAAAvrwgAAAAAAAAAAAGYTThsAAAAQNfMzvUEFp3C0E3PAbXf35oIQgnqX53f2fQSDTB1W6X7W46IoA1YmLNBZ/etmLIVUhSObKWEOnMTbW5FHMNuRAY="

[image]

---

**Step 2 - decode XDR**

With the "envelope_xdr", decode it to get the raw information (Using SDK @CLI, or Laboratory @UI):

For UI, we use laboratory: https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test

[image]

---

And you get all the 3 things

> - The name/code of the token
> - The amount transferred
> - The address the transaction was sent to

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks alot for the answer. The horizon API is helpful but does not solve the problem in my case. Given a transaction Hash I need to lookup 3 things

Comment: overread your question, now edited :)

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed response. As you can see above I found the answer using the Oraclize service itself. I do have another question, to check wether the transferred asset is XLM Lumens I only have to chec for key `asset_type` to be `native` correct? Example: https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/95356713582018561

Comment: yes, `asset_type=native` always and only refers to XLM. Note that anyone can create an asset with `asset_code=XLM`, but the `asset_type` will be `alphaNum4` instead of  `native`.